# What is the best method to instantiate a struct in run time?

Tags: go, design-patterns

I am currently writing a cache wrapper which will read the config and return what is the cache type (redis/memecache)

Now I have 
`redis.go` and `memcache.go` which has functions like

`initialize(), getCache(), setCache()`

My cache wrapper is my entry point and it returns

> Redis or Memcache as a "string"

as output. Now I want to call the initialize function of either redis/ memcache depending on the string. How do I do it?

I want to make sure that the implementation of this cache wrapper is so generic that, even if I add another cache type (eg: aerospike) tomorrow and I should not even be the changing the cache wrapper file.

It should be independent of how many and the kind of variants that I have for doing the cache.

Comment: Inspect the value of the string. If it's "redis" then call the redis initialization. If it's "memache" then call the memcache initialization.

Comment: @pdexter U mean switch case?

Comment: @LokanadhamMotumarri that will work, yes.

Comment: Any conditional will work. An if, a switch, a lookup table. There is no "best".

Comment: @pdexter In that case, I need to edit the cache wrapper every time I add a new cache type. Let's say, I add aerospike tomorrow. I don't wanna change the cache wrapper file. Writing the functionalities for aerospike alone should be enough.

Comment: @Rahul Okay, I think that's a different question than what's in the original post. This is now about how to add new functionality for new variants without changing the dispatcher. For this you could, for example, keep a map which maps strings to initialization functions. Another option is to use interfaces, where structs are created using the value of the string.

Comment: @Rahul Please edit your question with what you wants to achieve exactly.

Comment: Yeah exactly. As of now, I have achieved it through maps. Just asking if there is a better approach for the same. @pdexter

Comment: @Rahul without knowing more specifics I'd say that approach is fine